# Extracting legend of the plot in Altair

Tags: altair

I am trying to extract the legend of the plot in Altair. The problem is that I have trouble finding a way to remove the square and the circle inside the square next to the legend. Here is a sample code and the result I have. Any suggestion and help is appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['a','b','c'],
                    'y':[1,2,3]})

legend = alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    color=alt.Color('x:N')
)
legend
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "extract" the legend, but you could make the rest of the plot invisible (there will still be some whitspace to the left):

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_point(size=0).encode(
    color=alt.Color('x:N')
).configure_view(strokeWidth=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if/how the legend can be extracted from a chart, but if you only want the correct mapping you could simply create a custom plot that serves as a legend:

```py
pseudo_legend = alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    alt.Y('x',axis=alt.Axis(orient = 'right', tickSize=0, titleAngle=0, titleAnchor='start', titlePadding=-22)),
    color=alt.Color('x:N', legend=None),
    size=alt.value(80)
).configure_axis(
    grid=False,
    domain=False
).configure_view(
    strokeWidth=0
)
pseudo_legend
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
legend.configure_view(strokeWidth=0)
```

[image]